# Python Help: Create a method in each class that returns string that can later be used to build a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, github-api, class-attributes

We are building an application that is essentially consuming the GitHub REST API version 3 in order to collect data about various repos, pull requests, and their users. With this I need to then... 
(1) Within each class (repo, pull_requests, and users), I need to create a method that returns a string of all the collected data in basic csv format. 
(2) In a different method outside of these classes, I will take in that string and append it to a csv file.

I am stuck on part (1)...I am trying to come up with the best method to store data from that current search within that class, so that I can access it later in order to append it to a CSV file. Does anyone have any recommendations or suggestions?

I know I can use `__str__` or `__repr__` to return strings of the class attributes, but I'm not sure this makes sense here? We are already using `__str__` to return a string for a different reason, basically for when we are searching for repos, it just returns some basic details and prints it to our user interface

Comment: So these classes repo, pull etc represent a single repo, single pull etc?

Comment: Yes, they should to my understanding. The way we have it set up right now is that we do one search at a time, so we should be pulling data from one repo, user, etc at a time. Each time we do our search, I want to append the collected data from each of those classes to a respective csv file

Comment: wouldn't something like `',',join([str(i) for i in (x,y,z)])` work? where x,y,z etc are the objects of class repo, pull_requests, users etc

Comment: So, I've tried similar things and I get the object memory locations (I think that's what they are if I remember correctly, I'm still fairly new to this). For example, I added your code into our repo class ```def create_str (self):
        newstr = ',',join([str(i) for i in (self.owner,self.reponame,self.stargazers)])
        print (newstr)``` but when I call it later on to do a test, I get: ```repo = Repo("Insert Repo Name Here")
repo.create_str``` output: ```<bound method Repo.create_str of <__main__.Repo object at 0x0000019F45D5FBA8>>```